# How to use proc sql in sas and the in statement from another table

Tags: sql, sas

```
proc sql;
   create table X as
   select a.date, a.exdate
   from optionm.opprcd as a
   where a.volume>0
     and a.secid in (secids);
quit;
```

I want to do something like the above. Create a table taking data when the variable secid has values that appear in a table called "secids". Since the values that I want are approximately 600 I cannot use in (100, 101, etc). I need to somehow extract these values from another table.

Any help would be much appreciated, since I am not an expert in SAS.

Answer (score 3):

```
proc sql;
create table X 
as select 
a.date,
a.exdate
from optionm.opprcd as a
where a.volume>0
and a.secid in (select /*column*/secid from /*table*/secids)
;quit;
```

note - **quit!**

Comment: I realize this doesn't exactly need a lot of explanation, but *something* other than just code would be good - like a link to a sql tutorial explaining how to do an 'in' subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
    create table X as
    select a.date, a.exdate
    from optionm.opprcd as a,sec_tab b
    where a.secid=b.secids and a.volume>0;
quit;
```

NOTE: Basically, Join is faster than subquery.